# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML') when local development

Tags: javascript, html

I've below `HTML` code -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Intro to Js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"> </link>
    <script type="text/Javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>Introduction to Javascript</h1>
    <hr/>
    <div id="ResultContainer"></div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

below javascript `scripts/index.js`

```js
var resultContainer = document.getElementById("ResultContainer");
resultContainer.innerHTML = "Setting up environment";
```

below is the css/style.css

```css
body {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
}

#ResultContainer {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 450 px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

when I run the code using start command I get error

> Uncaught TypeError: resultContainer is null
>  http://localhost:3000/scripts/index.js:6

[image]

But the same code in [codepen](https://codepen.io/rajkumar51/pen/yLQvBWR) is running fine.

### Any idea how can I fix the error in local?

Comment: Maybe Codepen moves some logic only when DOM is ready? You did not specify at which lifecycle point you are  creating resultContainer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is running before the DOM is fully loaded (element does not exists).

To solve the issue you can either place the *script* at the bottom of the *body* tag or wrap your code with [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) which will ensure that your code executes only after the page is fully loaded:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  var resultContainer = document.getElementById("ResultContainer");
  resultContainer.innerHTML = "Setting up environment";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the script tag doesn't go in the header as it won't be able to read the boyd elements, put it in the body tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Intro to Js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"> </link>
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>Introduction to Javascript</h1>
    <hr/>
    <div id="ResultContainer"></div>
    <script type="text/Javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```